# Changing a filter in a view without modifying the filter clone?

Tags: views

I duplicated a block from view using clone display, but when I change the language on the block cloned filter, the filter is changed in the master view also. How to avoid this? I need 3 blocks, the block to master the English language and the other 2 blocks to English and Spanish.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you're changing a filter, before you apply there's a dropdown box. It's probably set to "All displays (except overridden)" by default. Before you hit Save, change that All Displays to "This display only"

Comment: Thanks for replying but in my view this option does not appear All Display. Must add that filter or it should come as standard on cloning?

Comment: Are you on Drupal 6 or 7? If on Drupal 6 then it's a bit different, you have to push the "Override" button when editing the filter.